# error : unhashable type = 'list'

Tags: python, collections, counter

I'm trying to collect errors from a file and I need to count them 
this is the output I need : [ error1 : 6 , error2 : 3 , error3 : 2]

```
import os,sys
import collections
Data = []
errors = []
with open('out.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            Data.append([word for word in line.strip().split("\t")])
for item in Data:
    try:
        date,error = item[0],item[5]
        errors.append(error.split('\n'))
    except IndexError:
        print "A line in the file doesn't have enough entries."

counter = collections.Counter(errors)
print counter
```

Comment: I think you want `errors.extend(..)` not `errors.append(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

You write:

```
errors.append(error.split('\n'))
```

Now `error.split('\n') will **return a list**. As a result,`error` is *not* a list of strings, but a list of list of strings. You probably want to replace it with:

```
errors += error.split('\n')
```

Now `errors` will be a list of strings, and strings are hashable items.